# Invalid cameras calibration for an head mounter Eye Tracking system

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, eye-tracking

I'm working on an Eye Tracking system with two cameras mounted on some kind of glasses. There are optical lenses so that the screen is perceived at around 420 mm from the eye.

From a few dozen pupil samples, we compute two eye models (one for each camera), located in their respective camera coordinates system. This is based on [the works here](https://github.com/LeszekSwirski/singleeyefitter), but modified so that an estimation of the eye center is found using some kind of brute-force approach to minimize the ellipse projection error on the model given its center position in camera space.

Theorically, an approximation of the cameras parameters would be symetrical to the lenses on the Y axis. So every camera should be at the coordinates (around 17.5mm or -17.5, 0, 3.3) with respect to the lenses coordinates system, a rotation of around 42.5 degrees on the Y axis.

With the However, with these values, there is an offset in the result. See below:

[image]
[image]

- The red point is the gaze center estimated by the left eye tracker, the white one is the right eye tracker, in screen coordinates
- The screen limits are represented by the white lines.
- The green line is the gaze vector, in camera coordinates (projected in 2D for visualization)
- The two camera centers found, projected in 2D, are in the middle of the eye (the blue circle).
- The pupil samples and current pupils are represented by the ellipses with matching colors.

The offset on x isn't constant which mean the rotation on Y is not exact. and the position of the camera aren't precise too. In order to fix it, we used: [this](http://sourishghosh.com/2016/stereo-calibration-cpp-opencv/) to calibrate and then [this](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node103.html) to get the rotation parameters from the rotation matrix.

We added a camera on the middle of the lenses (Close to the theorical 0,0,0 point ?) to get the extrinsics and intrinsic parameters of the cameras, relative to our lens center. However, with about 50 checkerboard captures from different positions, the results given by OpenCV doesn't seems correct.
For example, it gives for a camera a position of about (-14,0,10) in lens coordinates for the translation and something like (-2.38, 49, -2.83) as rotation angles in degrees.

The previous screenshots are taken with theses parameters. The theorical ones are a bit further apart, but are more likely to reach the screen borders, unlike the opencv value.

This is probably because the test camera is in front of the optic, not behind, where our real 0,0,0 would be located (we just add the distance at which the screen is perceived on the Z axis afterwards, which is 420mm).
However, we have no way to put the camera in (0, 0, 0).

As the system is compact (everything is captured within a few cm^2), each degree or millimeter can change the result drastically so without the precise value the cameras, we're a bit stuck.

Our objective here is to find an accurate way to get the extrinsic and intrisic parameters of each cameras, so that we can compute a precise position of the center of the eye of the person wearing the glasses, without other calibration procedure than looking around (so no fixation points)

Right now, the system is precise enough so that we get a global indication on where someone is looking on the screen,but there is a divergence between the right and left camera, it's not precise enough. Any advice or hint that could help us is welcome :)